# XPathでbody要素のテキストだけを取得する際、JavaScriptタグ内容だけは削除したい

Tags: php, dom

**意味はあまり分かっていないのですが、とりあえず下記のように書いたら、body要素の(恐らくタグを除いた)テキスト部分だけを取得できたのですが、**

```
$crawler->filterXPath('//body')->each(function (DomCrawler $node) use ($url) {
    $result = trim($node->text());
});
```

・[DomCrawler](http://docs.symfony.gr.jp/symfony2/components/dom_crawler.html)

---

**例えば、下記構成の場合は、JavaScriptタグ内容も取得してしまいます。**

```
<body>
  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
      var spaceid = "1160003246";
//以下略
  </script>
```

---

**質問**

・XPathでbody要素のテキストだけを取得する際、JavaScriptタグ内容だけは削除するにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？

Comment: 例えば`$html = preg_replace("/<script.*<\/script>/", "", $html) ;`のような処理をしてから`$crawler = new Crawler($html);` のようにすればどうでしょうか？

Comment: 他との絡みがあるため、出来れば「取得する際に条件分岐で除外」したかったのですが、難しいようなので、コメントいただいた考え方(事前削除)を検討しようと思います。参考になりました

Comment: DOMツリーをたどってテキストを拾うような関数を自作するようなこともできるかと思いますが、`preg_replace`と`strip_tags`を使うのが簡易だと思います。

Comment: scriptを除外するXPathを書けばいいです。XPathはこれが参考になるかと思います。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155948/xpath-select-child-elements-that-do-not-have-a-specific-name